# scrapy response.text not being updated for two different urls

Tags: python, json, api, scrapy

So, i have two differents parse functions withing the main main parse function. Pretty normal, as it seems.

```
class abcspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'abc'
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = [The main url where products are located]

    def parse(self, response):
        "Extracted the url of each product located on the main url and created a list to loop through"
        for url in urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parseproduct)


    def parseproduct(self, response):
        """Parse the page for some data and get a product id to form url1 and url2 from their respective url prefixes, which is already known"""
        urls = [url1+url2]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parsejson)

    def parsejson(self, response):
        """Parse the page for some data and get a product id"""
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        required_field = data["stock"]
```

The problem is that response.text for two different urls is not being updated in the cache. So, i'm getting the same results for the two different urls. i have verified and viewed that the response.url is returning the correct urls for both the function call but, apparently, the response body is not being updated in the second call of the function.

Any suggestions?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIe3M.jpg)

Comment: Have you noticed anything in the logs about duplicate URLs being filtered out?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIe3M.jpg

No, But I do see a request_depth_max value set two 2. I wonder what it’s for

Comment: Could you go into more detail of your code? I tried to reconstruct your problem but for me its working fine. I'm receiving two different results for the two urls as expected:
`{'info': [{'distance': 0.08046720000000002, 'id': 3124, 'displayName': 'Thunder Bay Supercentre',.....` and `{'info': [{'distance': 0.04828032, 'id': 3106, 'displayName': 'Dufferin Mall Supercentre',.....`.